# Minified React error #321 - error importing React component from published package

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import a React component from a package that I published and render it using ReactDOM.render. The package is published on gemfury and uses parcel to build.

I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321
```

when I try to render it in my project. This is how I am using it:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React from 'react'
import { Component } from '@me/library'

const container = document.querySelector(
  '#container'
)
const component_props = {name: 'john doe', ... }
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Component, component_props), container
)
```

The error that it throws indicates that I am using hooks outside of a functional component (I'm certain I am not doing that) or that I have multiple versions of react. Every test listed on the React site shows that there is only one version of React (16.13.1) being run. I have tried every fix that the React documents suggest and no luck. Why am I getting this error when there is only one version of React? How can I import a component from an external package and render successfully?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Component from 'package'

...

render(<Component name='Name'/>, // container)
```

I'm not sure you should be using `createElement` here.